# Import RCDATA resource to Visual Studio project via command line

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, msbuild

When I want import new resource to Visual Studio manually I right click on the project folder (In the Solution explorer), and go to Add->Resource->Import (find my required file) and set type as 'RCDATA'.

My problem is that the required file (to be imported) is changing frequently and I want to automate the build process to import a modified file automatically.

Is there a way to override an imported resource via command line? 
Or import again via command  line? (my auto build process will be ran in command line)

Comment: When you import a resource, that just adds the file name to the project. Every time you build, the data that's in the file at that moment will be baked into the executable. Really no different than adding a source file to the project. You don't need to re-import the file every time it changes.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik you're right, can you add your comment as an answer so I will mark it?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to override an imported resource via command line? Or
>   import again via command line? (my auto build process will be ran in
>   command line)

I'm afraid the answer is negative. For a C++ project, if we import a resource, actually the resource is controlled by .rc file. Please check this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ResourceCompile Include="MyProject.rc" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Image Include="..\..\..\..\Desktop\vs.png" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

The Image Item is used to display vs.png in Solution Explorer(For UI). Actually the resource compile is controlled by MyProject.rc, and the content of it would be like:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// PNG
//

IDB_PNG1                PNG                     "C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\vs.png"
```

We can pass parameters via command-line to project file(.vcxproj), but I have no idea how to pass parameter via command-line to the .rc file which is called by .vcxproj file. (Hope I don't misunderstand your meaning, if I have any understanding, feel free to correct me!)